# Disconnect users with Idle time greater than or equal to 1hr

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am writing a script that will filter the servers based on whether there are users logged in or not. If there is no user logged in, the script will export the name of the server to a text file. If there are users logged in, the script will go through the users and remove those that are either disconnected or have an idle time of greater than 60min.

I've completed the first filter, but I am unable to filter the idle time and pick out which users have idle time over 60min, I was able to filter those who have been logged in for more than a day, but I don't think this helps.

I've included the relevant code below:
Thank you.

```
$Servers = Get-Content 'H:\main\computernames.txt'
$openservers =@()
foreach ($Server in $Servers)
{
    if (-not( Test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet )) { continue }

    if (-not( Convert-QueryToObjects $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))
    {

     $openservers += $server
     $openservers | Out-File 'H:\main\server\openservers.txt'
 }

    else
    {  
        Convert-QueryToObjects -Name $Server | Where-Object  {@('Active','Disconnected') -contains $_.SessionState} | select @{Name='Server Name';Expression={$_.ComputerName}},
        @{Name='Username'; Expression={$_.Username}}, @{Name='Session State'; Expression={$_.SessionState}}, @{Name='Idle Time'; Expression={$_.IdleTime}}, @{Name='ID'; Expression={$_.ID}}

    if((Convert-QueryToObjects -Name $Server|?{@('Disconnected') -contains $_.SessionState}) -or (Convert-QueryToObjects -Name $Server|Where-Object {[datetime]$_.LogonTime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)}))

    {

        H:\WindowsPowerShell\Get-LoggedOnUser.ps1 -ComputerName $Server | Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -Verbose 
        Write-Output "--------------------------------"  

    }


  }
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for `(get-date).AddMinutes(-60)`? What format is `IdleTime` in?

Comment: @BenH Yes, but I've already tried that format, with no luck. I posted the complete code in gist here [link] https://gist.github.com/ruslive109/7c8c361fa0367a05e908586db1d38f06 [/link]

Comment: @BenH thank you for your input, I was considering implementing this filter: 'Where-Object {($_.IdleTime -like "*:*") -and ($_.IdleTime -gt "00:59")}' would you say this would work for multiple days?

Comment: Doing some testing that should work for this case, if you ever lowered the time to compare on under an hour you would need to do a little more work to handle the single digit idle times.